# Using jQuery Callback to Do two Things in Sequence

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to do two things in sequence.

1. Submit an HTML form that re-opens the page
2. Scroll to a specific point in the page

The HTML in the page is

```
<p>Zoom to <span class='links world'>the World</span>.</p>
<form id="world" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="world" value = "world">
</form>
```

Then the jQuery is

```
$(".world").click(function(){
$("#world").submit(), function(){
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#mapspace").offset().top}, 800);
};
});
```

It submits the form and re-opens the page, but it doesn't scroll. In isolation, both the submit and the animate work.

I am thinking perhaps that the callback is executed as soon as the form is submitted, and not when the page has reloaded. In which case, how do I make this work? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: If you can use an ajax call, you can see the page scrolling because there is no reload of the page

Comment: Reproductible exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

I think my assumption was correct: the callback was being executed on completion of the form being submitted and not when the page reloaded. My solution is a bit messy because it involves using PHP to write jQuery, but it works.

So now the HTML is

```
<p>Zoom to <span class='links world'>the World</span>.</p>
<form id="world" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="zoomto" value = "world">
</form>
```

The jQuery is:

```
$(".world").click(function(){
$("#world").submit();
});
```

And there's an extra bit of PHP at the end:

```
<?php if($_POST['zoomto']=='world') {
echo'<script>';
echo '$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#mapspace").offset().top -15}, 200);';
echo'</script>';
} ?>
```